# How to compile, and install ext-pdo_sqlite for php 7.2 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, sqlite

I would love to

```
apt-get install php7.2-pdo-sqlite
```

However, it is not present in the repo I am using, only php7.2-sqlite3 is...

My question is, How can I go about downloading, compiling and installing the following package for php 7.2

```
ext-pdo_sqlite
```

EDIT:

I have tried the following command

```
pecl install pdo_sqlite
```

but I got the following error

```
/tmp/pear/temp/PDO/pdo.c:371:2: error: too many arguments to function 'zend_hash_get_current_data_ex'
  while (SUCCESS == zend_hash_get_current_data_ex(&pdo_driver_hash, (void**)&pdriver, &pos)) {
  ^
In file included from /usr/include/php/20170718/Zend/zend.h:34:0,
                 from /usr/include/php/20170718/main/php.h:36,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/PDO/pdo.c:28:
/usr/include/php/20170718/Zend/zend_hash.h:205:30: note: declared here
 ZEND_API zval* ZEND_FASTCALL zend_hash_get_current_data_ex(HashTable *ht, HashPosition *pos);
                              ^
make: *** [pdo.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi just run from console `apt-get install php7.2-sqlite3`. It worked for me. It configures pdo driver in the process. You migh have to add this grat repo to your list of repositories: [https://deb.sury.org/][1]